# Stop notifications from displaying in a popup

Tags: android, notifications, progress-bar, notificationmanager

I am writing an Android App that is designed to perform a task over a period of time.

I have created a layout with a ProgressBar to indicate in the status how far through the process it is.

The problem I face is that in the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomExpandedView) it says:

```
mNotificationManager.notify(CUSTOM_VIEW_ID, notification);
```

As the code used to create / update your Notification. This is fine to an extent, the Notification updates itself with the new values for the progress bar that I have set. The problem is that every time I create an update Android spawns a new popup display telling me that I have an update (Android 3.1.1). This means that throughout the whole process I cannot open the status section.

**TL;DR:** The main part of this question, is to ask how I can get the Notification to stop creating a popup every time it is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this problem was caused by not using this flag:

Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE